# find class object calling specific method

Tags: python-3.x

I have 4 class that 3 of them inherit from each other. method 'f' called by object d  from class D. how can I find out that method 'f' called from an object belonging to class D???

I searched in module inspect but it is really confusing for beginners like me.

```
class A:
    def f(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class B(A):
    def g(self, a):
        return a*10

class C(A):
    def g(self, a):
        return a**2

class D(C, B):
    pass
########################
d = D()
print( d.f(3, 4) )
```

Comment: What part are you confused about? Your wording is confusing. Are you confused how `D` can call `f` from `A`? Or do you want to know which class `D` went through to get to `A`?

Comment: This should explain everything you want to know: [Method resolution order in Python Inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/). It even uses the same example.

Comment: `if self.__class__ == D: print("form D")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this additional print statement will do just that:

```
class A:
    def f(self, a, b):
        print(f"f called from an instance of {self.__class__.__name__}")
        # or:
        # print(f"f called from an instance of {type(self)}")
        return a + b
```

for you example it will print:

```
f called from an instance of D
```